# How to get specific value from JSON result return from REST call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am trying to fetch value from json result which is return from a REST call in my javascript .
Below is the JSON result of the REST

```
{
    "self": "http://example.com/rest/api/2/project/MTS/role/10002",
    "name": "Administrators",
    "id": 10002,
    "description": "A project role that represents administrators in a project",
    "actors": [{
        "id": 10803,
        "displayName": "Administrator ",
        "type": "atlassian-user-role-actor",
        "name": "admin",
        "avatarUrl": "/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10108"
    }, {
        "id": 10590,
        "displayName": "jira-administrators",
        "type": "atlassian-group-role-actor",
        "name": "jira-administrators",
        "avatarUrl": "/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10123"
    }]
}
```

from this result i only need to fetch all the actors name 
Can some one please help me with the below script

```
function getName()
{
var user;
     $.ajax({
        url: "/rest/api/2/project/MITS/role/10002",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            user = data;
       } 
     });
     return user;
}
```

The above script is not correct Please help

Comment: What is the output `console.log(user)`? Try putting it and see if you get something in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in success function, use this

```
users = []; // you will store the names here
$.each(data.actors, function(i,actor){
    if(actor.type === "atlassian-user-role-actor"){
        users.push(actor.name);
    }
})
```

an in users you will get the actors names

If you want, copy paste your JSON to http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and you will clearly see what the 'data' object has and how to access it.

Comment: Hi Antonis , one more things . I need to get only those actors where type = "atlassian-user-role-actor" . Please can you help

Comment: I edited it, it's simple I think.

Comment: Thanks :) I still dont know why my questions get down votes .. anyways thanks again

Comment: I guess because you want very specific answers ( so to solve your own problem ). Try to be more generic, and try to learn how to solve generic problems, not specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the actors array by accessing it like `data.actors`

Then iterate over the array using a `$.each` or a `for loop`

```
$.each(data.actors, function(i, val) {
   console.log('Actor name :: ' + val.name)
});
```